# Text To Speech settings in the agent for Dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

In Dialogflow ES we had an option to enable Automatic Text To speech for audio synthesis at agent, see the image below

---

[image: Enable Text To Speech option]

I could not find similar settings in Dialogflow CX ? is this option there somewhere else in CX ?

Comment: found any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Dialogflow CX console doesn’t have the ‘Automatic Text To speech’ option for audio synthesis yet.

However, Dialogflow CX has advanced speech settings which are applicable for telephony integrations and specialized partner integrations. For more information, check the [Speech and IVR settings](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent#settings-speech) section. Moreover, you can also use Dialogflow CX’s [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/library/overview), [Rest API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest), or [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc?hl=en) to create speech responses that can be added as described at [RPC API's OutputAudioConfig](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.OutputAudioConfig) and [REST API's OutputAudioConfig](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/OutputAudioConfig) on your [StreamingDetectIntentRequest](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#streamingdetectintentrequest) and [detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.sessions/detectIntent) method respectively.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to easily convert your CX agent to a voicebot by adding nice Speech Synthesis I recommend you to try Voximplant DF CX connector.
They have several Text to Speech providers like Amazon, Google, Azure and IBM.
The integration is really simple check the process here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kp5haQ7zNQ
Check the docs here - https://voximplant.com/docs/howtos/integration/nlp_nlu/df_cx_inbound